# How to set Toolbar text and back arrow color

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

Toolbar background is dark color, I want text and back arrow to be white. I tried following, but it doesnt work.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_darker</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple</item>
        <!-- item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item--> // I don't want to set this, changes everywhere. 
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ToolbarStyle</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/AppTheme.DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ToolbarStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <!--<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.OverflowButtonStyle</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> // doesn't work
        <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Try to add `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` to your `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`; back arrow and text will be white, like @yubarajpoudel said.

Answer (score 163):

Chances are you are extending from the wrong parent. If not, you can try adding the `style` to the `toolbar` layout directly, if you want to override the theme's settings.

In your toolbar layout:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ToolBarPopupStyle"
      android:background="@color/actionbar_color" />
```

In your styles:

```
 <!-- ToolBar -->
  <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
      <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
      <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
      <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>      
      <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflowStyle</item>
      <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: giving error while adding this style to `styles.xml` file

Comment: you don't need the drawerArrowStyle part to make answer the question

Answer (score 136):

Add the following as toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in the layout where you needed

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Enjoy

Comment: Yes, works! Particularly `app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`.

Comment: Should be `<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`

Answer (score 68):

Inside Activity, you can use

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

If you love to choose xml for both title color & back arrow white just add this style in style.xml .

```
 <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And toolbar look like :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  />
```

Comment: THIS WORKS!
So many random answers - I think the thing to note is this works for:
   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
nested within:
   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Many thanks

Comment: the java solution does not change the arrow color

Answer (score 25):

This solution might be easier. But it does require a higher API version(23). simply add this code to your toolbar in XML:

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:titleTextColor="#ffffffff" />
```

Comment: @VygintasB true

Comment: It is not necessary to set android:titleTextColor="#ffffffff", just         android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" and         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

Answer (score 19):

If you use `AndroidX` (as of July 2019) 
you may add these:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
  app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"/>
```

NOTE! This was tested to work if your `Toolbar` is placed directly inside `AppBarLayout` but not inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Answer (score 14):

this method helped me.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/highlightRed</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: This is the answer if you're having an `appbarlayout`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/actionBar"
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleText"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/ToolbarTitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="hh"/>
```

```
<!-- ToolBar -->
<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#ff63BBF7</item>
</style>
```

use app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"

[Reference resources：http://blog.csdn.net/wyyl1/article/details/45972371](http://blog.csdn.net/wyyl1/article/details/45972371)

Comment: Please explain your answers, just posting code isn't very clear for answering a question.

Answer (score 5):

Add this line to `Toolbar`. 100% working

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your XML file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

And add this is your colors.xml file

```
    <color name="colorAccent">YOUR_COLOR</color>
```

Comment: Please can you share with us what was in the app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"

Answer (score 3):

This approach worked for me using the Material Components library:

In `styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Your styles here -->

    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48205577/238753

Answer (score 1):

Try a lot of methods, in the low version of the API,a feasible method is `<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>` and don't use the Android namespace

ps:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- change the textColor -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionMenuTextColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used placeholders so just follow along, as you might want to still keep the inheritance from the original style.

Before

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/{{originalBaseStyle}}"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

After:

styles.xml

```
<style name="{{yourToolbarStyle}}" parent="{{originalBaseStyle}}">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonOverflowStyle</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Therefore

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/{{yourToolbarStyle}}"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If we follow the activity template created by Android Studios, it's the AppBarLayout that needs to have an android theme of AppBarOverlay, which you should define in the your styles.xml. That should give you your white color toobar/actionbar color text.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">  ...
```

In styles.xml, make sure the following exists:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_primary"
    android:theme="@style/GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
```

That toolbar theme specifies a textColorPrimary and textColorSecondary to change the color of the title text and of the menu overflow button. You could just specify the standard Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme for the toolbar, to get the dark text and overflow icon,  but I wanted to derive from my own theme and make only small changes, because I have no idea what else might be affected.

```
<style name="GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">


<!-- android:textColorPrimary is the  color of the title text
   in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat theme:  -->
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item>

<!-- android:textColorPrimaryInverse is the  color of the title
   text in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat.Light theme:  -->

<!-- <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abc_primary_text_material_light</item> -->
```

This is how you can change the color of text and icons on toolbar.

For more
Ref: https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/

Comment: Also set the <item name="android:textColorHint"> in the style.xml to the same color as your text or it will look strange! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines in Basic application theme, first for text, second for icon of menu

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorTextWhite</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextWhite</item>
```

It would look like this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorTextWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the Toolbar's back icon drawable you can use this:

Add the `<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>` into your Theme.

And here is the `ToolbarStyle` itself:

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using the latest iteration of Android Studio 3.0 and generating your Activity classes, in your styles files change this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

To this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```