# ReactNative ToolbarAndroid overflow icon is black - can I change its color or do I need to replace it altogether?

Tags: react-native, android-toolbar

Can I change the right icon's overflow color from black to white?

[image: Toolbar]

Or is my only option the "overflowIcon" property?

> **overflowIcon** optionalImageSource
>
> Sets the overflow icon.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Icon.ToolbarAndroid` from https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons instead of the standard RN `ToolbarAndroid` and it works for me hope this helps. Have not found any property that allows us to customise the standard icon color so far but if you want to use the standard component then i believe the only way to do this is by editing your `styles.xml` [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969424/how-to-set-toolbar-text-and-back-arrow-color)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons 
and set both `overflowIconName` and `iconColor` properties:

```
<Icon.ToolbarAndroid
  style={styles.toolbar}
  title={displayTitle}
  titleColor={textColor}
  iconColor={textColor}
  overflowIconName="more-vert"
  // ... more props
/>
```