# Unable to text Toolbar text color

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have this code in my Activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setTitle("My title");
```

In `styles.xml`, I have this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    //more stuff
</style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Toolbar.Text</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and the Toolbar layout:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
     app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
```

I want the toolbar's text to be white, but it is black. I have tried lot of things but I really can't change it.

Comment: `app:titleTextColor` or `toolbar.setTitleTextColor`  not helping ?

Comment: It doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is, The issue is come from this line :

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

And this:  `app:theme="@style/Toolbar"` (You've used `app` instead of `android`, Be careful about that)

And you don't really need to do that.

---

Just use this line for the `Toolbar`:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

**So:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Then you should see the white text and etc

As you can see, I've set the `app:popupTheme` to `AppTheme` which the parameter is :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

After adding that line to the `Toolbar`, Now you can remove these:

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Toolbar.Text</item>
</style>

<style name="Toolbar.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then the only thing you should do is setting the parent for `app:popupTheme` to this :

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Which it can be your `Activity` style parent.

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the editor for this. Go to tools->android->theme editor. There you can find the option for changing the colors.

Comment: I have been able to change the text color by changing textColorPrimary in the app main style, but it changes all the text in another components, too. I just want it in the toolbar

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969424/how-to-set-toolbar-text-and-back-arrow-color) will help you.

Comment: and also, may be you have set the textColorPrimery for other texts too and hence the result.

Comment: I have tried all the answers of the link and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm using data binding in layout, does it matter?

Answer (score -1):

you may be using SDK less than 23 you can try this

In xml :-

```
android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
```

In fragment

```
 toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Now try above answer